# POCO X3 Pro - Bluetooth stays on

Tags: bluetooth

Recently aquired a POCO X3 Pro.

Problem is, I disable bluetooth (to conserve battery), however, after a reboot, bluetooth is enabled again. It says that Google Play Services turned it on.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does Google Play Services need bluetooth? Presumably its better not to disable Google Play Services. And why doesn't my Samsung behave the same way?